# How can I make an if statement that is true whenever an element from an array is inputed? (C)

Tags: c

Here is the code.

Right now im not using the array, but I don't want to put all those if statements.

This is just an example of my actual code.

```
int array[6] = {2,3,5,7,9,11};
int num;
printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &num);

if(num == 2 || num == 3 || num == 5 || num == 7 || num == 9 || num == 11 ){
    printf("True\n");
}
else{
    printf("False\n");
}
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop to iterate the elements of the array. `int ix; for (ix = 0; ix < sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); ix++) { ...}`

Comment: If the array values are in the [0...255] range, use `unsigned char[]` and `memchr()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

add this function into your code and call it when you need to check

```
    int valueinarray(float val, float arr[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == val)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Example**

```
int valueinarray(float val, float arr[]);
```

Comment: you can change datatype whatever you want for example: float to int or else.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int arry[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(arry); ++i){
    
    printf("\nNumber %d printed!", i);
    
    
    
    if(i == 2) // Replace '2' with user input.
    {
        printf("\nFound 2");
        break; // Exit loop because we found what we were looking for
    }
    else {
        // do something
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `sizeof(arry)` needs to be `sizeof(arry)/sizeof(arry[0])`

Comment: `if(i == 2)` needs to be `if(arry[i] == num)` where `num` is the user input value as shown in the OP code.